# convert sql query into relational algebra

Tags: relational-database, relational-algebra

I need help converting sql query into relational algebra.

So for example let’s say I have a random SQL query in English, made up of 5 parts:

- 1. Select all school in albany
- 2. get there total school gpa (student gpa’s / count student)
- 3. average school gpa < 3.5
- 4. limit top 10 schools
- 5. rank them by total school gps

So I have created into relational algebra.

```
σ rownum() > 0 & rownum() ≤ 10 
    (π student gpa’s / count student -> total school gpa 
         (σ school = ‘albany’ & total school gpa < 3.5 (school Table)))
```

my Question: Can some one double check my solution and let me know if this is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** You seem to be translating from SQL but you are not restricting yourself to features of whatever RA (relational algebra) you were given.
We can't answer your question without knowing your RA and the columns and meanings of your base relations.

---

If you want to think in terms of SQL, you need to find out how each RA operator would be expressed in SQL. There are no NULLs in RA. There are no row numbers in relations. Your RA may or may not have ordered attributes and/or duplicate attribute names and/or attributes with aliases dotted in them.  You need to be clear on what a "relation" is and what an "operator' is in your RA.

There are typically no functions but comparisons in RA. (Although if you haven't been given school average gpas then you need to use arithmetic division.) There is no count() or rownum(). There is typically no renaming in projection. Some RAs' selection/restriction operators don't allow boolean connectives. There's no sorting. Which you are relying on, but not asking for. You aren't clear about your base relation names or attributes or meanings.

Check out RelaX which executes a(n SQLish version of) RA.